# HTML is not rendered in error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I tried to un-downvote a question, an expected error message was displayed (more than an hour had passed since I voted).

However, the error message includes HTML tags which are not rendered:

[image]

The device is an LG Optimus L9.

Comment: Android toasts are just text. They'd have to write a custom view/popup to render that correctly.

Comment: @Bryan In this particular case, stripping the markup may be the preferred route. I don't think it adds enough value to warrant the cost of a custom view.

Comment: I agree, it would probably be easier to strip out the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the next build we will strip the HTML from the error messages.

Comment: Don't forget to replace it with blank space or something otherwise something like "You last voted on this question17 hours agoYour vote is now locked inunless this question is edited" will occur. :)

Comment: Thanks for the change. However, the problem foretold by the syllabically-muddled wizard has [come to pass](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192350/i-voted-on-this-answer2-days-agomy-vote-is-now-locked-inunless-the-answer-is-edi).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins yes, it has - a build has solved this issue.

Comment: I am regularly impressed by the speed at which you and other developers respond to these issues. Thank you for your work!