# I voted on this answer2 days agoMy vote is now locked inunless the answer is edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Simple display bug on the toast message:  words aren't spaced out enough.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... a little too ambitous with the HTML stripping? reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191286/html-is-not-rendered-in-error-message

Comment: I was going to jumpalloverthis title, but thenIlookedat theimage.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't jump on the title, since the other half magically materialized.  Also, for the HTML stripping, that would explain why it reads unusually, grammar-wise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A new build of API has fixed this issue.  Yes - I get the [told-you-so] badge.

Comment: You lucky people - you get to change the *API*, normal devs have to change their *apps* and hope the API *doesn't* change.